# Prevent TeamCity from building if comment changed

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I make some comment changes in the code. I dont want to trigger a build on this kind of changes as nothing really is going to be changed. And if I make several changes and make several quick commits I end up with a long build queue. Is there a way to set some kind of commit message or anything, that no build is triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing it but you could achieve it to some extent by using [VCS Trigger Rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules). You could add a rule to exclude check-ins with specific comment, say exclude check-in if the comment text contains "comment only". And then while checking in your comment only changes you need to include the text "comment only" in your comment.

Regarding several changes you can use below settings along with [Quiet Period Settings](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-QuietPeriodSettings)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very close to what I need. If there are no other options I will mark as answer.